# PHP sql arranging output

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting

i'm trying to rearrange user CHECKTIME and group it to their name

here is my sql query

```
SELECT TOP 10 MIN(u.BADGENUMBER) AS BADGENUMBER,c.USERID,u.NAME,u.TITLE,d.DEPTNAME,c.CHECKTIME
FROM CHECKINOUT c, USERINFO u, DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE u.USERID = {$user} AND  u.DEFAULTDEPTID = d.DEPTID {$date}
GROUP BY c.CHECKTIME,c.USERID,u.USERID,u.NAME,u.TITLE,d.DEPTNAME
ORDER BY d.DEPTNAME,u.NAME,c.CHECKTIME
```

this how the array output looks at this moment in time

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 215
        [USERID] => 437
        [NAME] => Axmed faarax maxamed
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => 26 June
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-12 06:52:41
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )

    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 215
        [USERID] => 437
        [NAME] => Axmed faarax maxamed
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => dkt
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-12 15:43:25
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 215
        [USERID] => 437
        [NAME] => Axmed faarax maxamed
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => dkt
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-13 06:38:52
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 213
        [USERID] => 434
        [NAME] => james roy
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => psk
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-13 15:49:27
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )

    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 213
        [USERID] => 434
        [NAME] => james roy
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => 26 June
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-14 06:58:52
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )
```

i need the data to output like this

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 215
        [USERID] => 437
        [NAME] => Axmed faarax maxamed
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => 26 June
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-12 06:52:41
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )
        [CHECKTIME2] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-12 15:43:25
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )
        [CHECKTIME3] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-13 06:38:52
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )


    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BADGENUMBER] => 213
        [USERID] => 434
        [NAME] => james roy
        [TITLE] => Lineman
        [DEPTNAME] => psk
        [CHECKTIME] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-13 15:49:27
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )
        [CHECKTIME2] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-05-14 06:58:52
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles
            )

    )
```

please if you could help me i been searching and trying different ways but i cannot get it done :(

Comment: *Jay* injection, don't you think too *Sam* @JayBlanchard :)?

Comment: *Hmmmmmm, could be RR.* ;-) @Rizier123

Comment: come on anyone pleaseeeee....

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL here...) Correct tagging improves the chance to get better answers, faster!